# How to define conditional function with Mathematica?

Tags: function-construction, conditional

How to define conditional function $f(x,y)$ with the following result. If $x=1$ and $y=0$ then $f=77$, if $x=0$ and $y=1$, then $f=66$, if $x$ and $y$ are all other integer values then $f=0$. How to define in Mathematica phrase 'all other values'?

```
f[x_,y_]:=Which[x==1 && y==0, 77, 
    x==0 && y==1, 66,
    "all other values of x,y", 0]
```

Comment: `True`? btw, what does `&& , ` mean, please pay attention. p.s. `Switch` would be more handy here, take a look at `Piecewise` too.

Comment: && means 'and'. Also || means 'or' as I know

Comment: I was concerned about `,` after `&&`.

Comment: Piecewise is working. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it's easier just to define this straight up, rather than compute something procedurally.

```
f[1, 0] = 77;
f[0, 1] = 66;
f[_, _] = 0;
```

*Mathematica* is fundamentally an expression rewriting system, so telling it how to rewrite expressions directly like this is usually clearer, faster, and easier to debug.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but you should test for integers in the third line.

Comment: @Kiro, of course one could do `f[_Integer, _Integer]` and perhaps that's what @Timur would like. However, my answer meets his specification: he did not state what should happen for non-integers, and his attempt suggests `0` was a general default.

Answer (score 4):

```
f[x_Integer, y_Integer] :=Which[x == 1 && y == 0, 77, x == 0 && y == 1, 66, True, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using Piecewise:

```
f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{77, {x, y} == {1, 0}}, {66, {x, y} == {0, 1}}}, 0]
```

(Piecewise takes as arguments an array of tupels {value,condition} and optionally a "default" value if all conditions are false.)

Answer (score 2):

The null represents "all other values". You can replace it with anything you like.

```
f[x_, y_] := If[x == 1 && y == 0, 77, If[x == 0 && y == 1, 66, If[IntegerQ[x] && IntegerQ[y], 0, null]]]
```

**Test it:**

```
f[1, 0]
```

OUT: 77

```
f[0, 1]
```

OUT: 66

```
f[9, -2]
```

OUT: 0

```
f[9, 1.1]
```

OUT: null

```
f[1.2, Pi]
```

OUT: null